# Creating a regression model of scaling data from five points for ATAR

Tags: regression, linear-regression

I am looking to calculate the scaled results for the ATAR (Australian Tertiary Admission Rank) subjects that someone inputs from the recently released 2023 data. For example if someone got a 59.00 in Accounting, their scaled result is 61.50. This data was released by QTAC here: https://www.qtac.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/2023_QTAC_ATAR_Report.pdf (Page 11-13)

I would like to know how I can get the values to calculate scores higher or lower than the data provided by QTAC. Thanks for the help.